# How to implement Mumble with RoR Application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We need one voice chat application integration in RoR application existing room users. How we can achieve that? Have any reference links or existing sample voice chat reference sites using mumble, it will help me lot.

Thanks,
Mars

Answer (score 0):

[Murmur manager](http://github.com/cheald/murmur-manager/) is a ruby library that provides control over a murmur daemon.  Should be enough to integrate mumble/murmur into a RoR app.